# Building solutions in different team projects

Tags: build, tfs, tfsbuild

I am having issues with creating a build. The build I am supposed to create is to refer to two different solutions. This was not an issue until I realized that the solutions are in different team projects. Is it possible for TFS to reference a Solution in a different team project by modifying the `<SolutionToBuild>` Property?

`TeamProject1
->Src
-->Solution1
--->Solution1.sln`

`TeamProject2
->Src
-->Solution2 
--->Solution2.sln`

TFSBuild.proj file is in Team Project 1 and we are using TFS2008.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

You can build any project or solution as long as you ensure that the solution or project file is pulled down via the work space and that you reference it correctly.

It uses reference paths just like when you reference a dll. It can be absolute or relative. You want to do it via a relative path.

It will look something like the below in your TFS.proj file. Depending on where your solution is of course.

`<SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../Solution1.sln">`

Hope this helps.